# Model view view model structure

Tags: java, android, mvvm

I want to understand the structure of MVVM architecture

Android MVVM Architecture:
[image: Screenshot]

Do I have to create a repository for every view that gets data from the server?
or Should I create a remote class for every view that gets data from the server and put this class instance on one repository class so, I have one repository class that holds all remote classes instance?

Answer (score 0):

There are some different approach you can use, The one that is common:

1. Make a Repository Interface for some specific data you need to store.
2. Implement a Concrete Repository based on where you want to access/save that data (Database, Remote, Memory, and ...)

For example, a Chat application has some Rooms (Direct) you want to store its info and message:

1. Make a Repository Interface: RoomRepository
2. For remote make a concrete class named RoomRemoteRepository and for Db access make RoomDatabaseRepository.
3. Based on your design you may even need a separate MessageRepository.

Make a Repository when you need to store and perform add, remove, update, find, and ... operation on that data.